# GUI for multiple OpenCV videos

Tags: user-interface, visual-c++, video, opencv

I want to build a GUI for a OpenCV application. What I want to accomplish is show multiple videos in one Window and show a tracker in the same window.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

First of all, if you're asking for help on the tracker, please consult the OpenCV documentation (cvNamedWindow and cvCreateTrackbar). As for having multiple videos in one window, it's relatively easy. All you need to do is create an image that can hold the frames for all of your videos. For example, if you have two videos @ 320x240 each, create a frame that can hold a 640x240 frame. Call off to cvQueryFrame (two times -- one for each source). Copy the first result into the left half of the image, and the second result into the right half. Then call off to cvShowImage with the concatenated images and you're done! Hope that helps :)

Comment: I think it would be a bit clumsy, wouldn't it? if the number of images increases to ... 12 or 16. Moreover, in many cases, there are still more needs for user input, a better GUI. Do you know any solution ?? Qt, may be MFC??